# How to make UIWebView Links open in a UIPopover?

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, uipopover

I currently have a simple HTML file loaded in a UIWebView with a bunch of  links embedded in the text of the file. I am wondering if there is a way to make these links open in a UIPopover.

The links are to another HTML file, so I would like them to load in a UIPopover with a UIWebView inside them.

Let me know if I haven't been clear enough as to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at this method of UIWebViewDelegate

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
            shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                        navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

This will get called whenever a user triggers a link

So make the viewController which contains the UIWebView into that webView's delegate, and implement this method.

If has a BOOL return value. If you return "NO" the webview itself will not attempt to handle the link, so you can take control of it.

`(NSURLRequest *)request` gives you the actual link...

So from here you can trigger a UIPopover with a content viewController... which can contain a UIWebView, in which you can load your link data.

(funny you should ask the question just this moment, I am implementing something similar right now..)

*update*

As you noticed, there is a subtlety to observe here. When your UIWebView first loads it's content (on viewDidLoad for example), this delegate method will be called. If you return `NO` under this condition, the initial content will not load, and you will have a mysteriously blank webView.

To fix this you need to consider the `navigationType` parameter. Basically you only want to return 'NO' if the navigationType is `UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked` (you activate a link). Otherwise you want to return `YES` (the webView should load it's content).

So a full implementation of the method might look like this

```
-               (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
   shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
               navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
  BOOL result = YES;
    if (navigationType=UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked){
        [self launchPopOverWithRequest:request]
        result =  NO;
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: I have one quick question. It's probably something stupid that I'm missing, but when I return NO, the html file that I have loaded in the UIWebView no longer shows up. Should I be loading the HTML file in a different place? I'm currently loading it in the viewDidLoad function of the ViewController.m for the current View Controller.